# How to prove that $(E_a;+,\times)$ is not a field

Tags: abstract-algebra

$ \forall a\in \mathbb{R}^*$ let  $E_a= \Bigg\{ M(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}
x & -ay \\
y & x
\end{pmatrix} \mid (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \Bigg\}$

let $A=M(0,1)$ and $a<0$

I have proved  that $A^2+aI=0_2$.

I have to conclude that  $(E_a;+,\times)$ is not a field.

I have tried to find the symmetry of an element of $E_a$ outside from $E_a$, but I couldn't find this element

Please help me with this question

Comment: Can you do the case $E_{-1}$?

Answer (score 2):

Since $a < 0$, $\sqrt{-a} > 0$ makes sense so you can factorize:
$$
0 = A^2 + aI = A^2 - (\sqrt{-a}I)^2 = (A + \sqrt{-a}I)(A - \sqrt{-a}I)
$$ Notice that both $A \pm \sqrt{-a}I \in E_a$ and neither are $0$ so $E_a$ has zero divisors.